# Is every buildable set that exists, by Extensionality, unique in ZF Set Theory?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I am reading *An Introduction To Set Theory* by *Professor William A. R. Weiss*, and during chapter 3, on the proof of $\forall x \forall y \exists z \ z = x\times y$ (the euclidean product exists), there's the following:

> We obtain:
> $$\forall t \in y \ \exists q \ q=\left\{ v : \exists u \in x \ v=\langle u,t \rangle \right\}$$
> By Extensionality, in fact, $\forall t \in y \ \exists ! q \ q=\left\{ v : \exists u \in x \ v=\langle u,t \rangle \right\}$.

This step seems intuitively clear, but it also doesn't seem like an special case, it seems like this logic could be applied to any set built using builder notation.

So my question is: For any arbitrary set $x$ and any abritrary formula $\Omega$, does $\exists q \ q=\left\{ v:\Omega \right\}$ imply, by Extensionality, that $\exists ! q \ q=\left\{ v:\Omega \right\}$?

Comment: Yes; the point is that a set is determined by its elements, so that two sets with the same elements are in fact the same set.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks man, this made the use of the Axiom of Replacement pretty "easy", so even though it's an obvious question, I wanted to be sure. If you want, you can write on an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what extensionality says.